# Shall I use HSM to decrypt message instead of using an application server that link to HSM to decrypt the message

Tags: email, encryption, messaging, hsm

Our company is using an HSM to store the private keys of individuals.  So the messages are all encrypted with their public keys.  The problem to me is that whether I should use a server to connect to the HSM to get the private key and then decrypt the message in the server or to pass the encrypted message to HSM and ask the HSM to decrypt for me (so that the key does not need to pass outside the HSM).  But, is HSM usuallyhas this function; if yes, will it be too slow?   The messages are emails and the instant messages.

Answer (score 1):

> ...whether I should use a server to connect to the HSM to get the private key and then decrypt the message in the server or to pass the encrypted message to HSM and ask the HSM to decrypt for me

If you have a proper HSM, never allow exporting the plain private keys out of it. Otherwise having an HSM to protect the keys would be useless. Just have the HSM to do the decryption on the data.

You can consider adding an application server to the picture anyway just to have an abstraction layer between your client applications and the HSM. Depending on the HSM you have, you probably have two options:

- Have an application server with a physical HSM attached (e.g. PCI-e card) exposing your own API to the client applications.
- Use networked HSM and register your application server as its client.

Typically (pretty much always) your code can consume the HSMs through PKCS#11 or similar interface / crypto engine (e.g. Chil for Thales HSMs). 
Especially for PKCS#11 there are plenty of libraries available for almost any programming language. HSM vendors also often provide their set of software libraries for you to consume.

The bottom line is that if your HSM is a proper FIPS approved HSM, allowing exporting the private keys would make your money being wasted.

> But, is HSM usuallyhas this function; if yes, will it be too slow?

Most of the general purpose HSMs are fast in general crypto operations. But again this depends greatly what kind of HSM you have.

Comment: Could you explain the details of the two options.  In particular, if I use the application server for the abstraction layer, do I need to pass the private keys to the application server for the decryption of my email message?

Answer (score 0):

> First rule of using HSM is never extract sensitive keys outside of
>   HSM.

This is illogical because you pay huge amount of money to purchase a HSM to store keys on it but your keys are still outside of HSM.

HSMs are for encrypting-decrypting small amount of data not for mass data cryptographic processing. For Emv cards,PINS, cryptograms etc. only small amounts are processed.

If you want to encrypt messages and emails(I think they are multiple MB size) you need to have multiple HSMs depends on your needs and its expensive.

On my previous company we had a solution to similar problem.  We have a Master Key on HSM that encrypt localy used master keys(LUMK) that used for encryption of mails,messages etc. We store LUMKs on database encrypted and when we need those keys we simply decrypt them on HSM and use on our program for cryptographic processing. This scheme provide sufficient protection for our keys and data.